# SQLite Android Select Random Row Excluding Certain Columns

Tags: android, sqlite, random

Is it possible to select a random row from an SQLite table however have the row return only specific column information for that row using Android rawquery sort by random? Example:

Table1

```
  C1      Col2   Col3    Col4

1 A       B      C       D

2 E       F      G       H

3 I       J      K       L

4 M       N      O       P

5 Q       R      S       T

6 U       V      W       X
```

Is it possible to randomly select a row between 1 and 6 excluding columns C1 and C3 thus returning:

J,L or N,P or V,X   etc...

Any examples of a raw query SELECT statement that would accomplish this?

Comment: There is no first and last row, at least not just according to the data you posted.  You need to tell us which _column_ determines which row is first and last.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I just need to know that if, for example, if row 2 is randomly chosen that selection F will be selected with selection H. Let assume that selection F is the label describing selection H so I need them to be together. It would just be one row that is selected at a time so I'm not concerned with the row order. I could have explained that more clearly in the question. I apologize.

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't answer my question.  Which _column_ determines which row is "first" and which row is "last?"

Comment: Apologies. Lets say that is C1.

Comment: Then my answer is one possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option, which assumes that the `C1` column determines the ordering:

```
SELECT Col2, Col4
FROM yourTable
WHERE C1 <> (SELECT MIN(C1) FROM yourTable) AND
      C1 <> (SELECT MAX(C1) FROM yourTable)
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @TimBiegelisen I chose your answer because it seems extremely complete and I will try to implement it if needed. However, as I said above I ended up using column indexes for the listview but now I need to populate TextViews instead of the ListView. I made a new question for that. Thanks again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786983/android-display-multiple-pieces-of-cursor-data-together-textviews-instead-of-a

Answer (score 1):

you can use this query

```
SELECT Col2, Col4 FROM yourTable ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I ended up just calling the colum indexes and it is producing the desired result as far as populating the ListView. I just posted another question about populating textViews instead of the ListViews with the information.

Answer (score 1):

Use of Random inside a Db query is not recommended, as it could be quite expensive operation , if your data is too big .
If it is 100 rows, then probably you can do whatever you want .

Random query traverses the whole db to generate Random row

Instead of that, you can do it in 2 steps
1) Find the count of rows 
2) calculate a random number using Math.random from 1 to count-1 ;
Then use the query as :

```
SELECT column FROM tableName LIMIT $random_number, 1
```

The process in both is same, but getting the random number inside sql query is expensive then getting it using Math.random()

Comment: i appreciate the suggestion. if it is more efficient I will try it. random() has been working for me so far.